# Throughput decreases after MTU 5000

Tags: networking, tcp, throughput, mtu

I am trying to test throughput between two computers directly connected through 1 GbE and testing with iperf. I am getting a throughput around 980Mbps when MTU is between 5000 and 5050, however it drastically falls to around 680Mbps anything above MTU=5050. I have checked varying window sizes, but with same result. Increasing the MTU should decrease the overheads and thereby should increase the bandwidth or at least should not fall. I can't figure out this strange behavior. By the way testing TCP throughput. Any help ! and thanks guys. This is my post ever on any forum :) usually I find answers....

Additional info! Two centos systmes, One of them is Xen 4.2 host (but it shouldn't be the problem) Checked with varying buffer sizes in /pro/sys/net/ipv4, but no same result. Latency is 0.2 ms.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly an implementation specific performance bottleneck somewhere.  You're correct in that *all other things equal* having larger MTUs will result in lower overhead and thus higher performance.  But other things are rarely equal...  here, some part of the forwarding/packet moving code probably has a base buffer size of 5KB or something like that, so when you cross that barrier, all of a sudden you're asking the system to do twice as much work.

One way to support this theory would be to increase the MTU even further.  If you see a big drop at 5KB, but then your thruput improves once beyond that, you've almost certainly hit some buffer size threshold somewhere in the code path.

Comment: ,tnx for the info. I will try testing with other tools. I don't have much knowledge about coding and stuff. I got a reply on this trade.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440454/throughput-decreases-after-mtu-5000.                                                                   Does TCP performance depends on memory page allocation?